# Including includes that contain the same includes

Tags: c++, include, xcode5

Ok, so I have my main.cpp:

```
#include "chromosome.h"
#include "functions.h"

int main(){
blah;
return 0;

}
```

'functions.h' and 'chromosome.h' both have:

```
#include <vector> 
#include <random> 
#include <math.h>
```

and this is causing the error:'linker command failed with exit code 1'.

Can anyone shed some light? I imagine this is a really simple thing. I'm using xcode 5.

Thanks all.

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem. Its most likely something else.

Comment: Have you read **any** C++ book? If yes, then take other books, where the linking is describe properly with the guards.

Comment: No, the error isn't caused by that.

Comment: put #pragma once in the beginning of every header file

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're having problems linking your files together? Go into Target Settings -> Build Phases and add your files to Compile Sources.

Comment: Thanks, what should be included here? I've got all the .cpp's in there already

Answer (score 0):

You should use #include gaurds in every header file, like this:

```
#ifndef MYHEADER
#define MYHEADER

/*your code here*/

#endif /* MYHEADER*/
```

You have to make sure the naming scheme does not conflict with other third party headers that may be used.

A more elegant solution is the #pragma once directive which is non-standard.

```
#pragma once

/*your code here*/
```